# Multiple users notify system

Tags: delphi

I have to create a notify system, which will be remind users about what the others do. If one of the user add some order, the other should see it as alert or something like that. 
So, my question is, which way is the best to do this. Should I use TTimer and ask every 5 minutes or you know better idea?

Sorry for extreamly poor english... I'm from Poland ;)

Comment: Could you explain exactly what do you mean by users? Multiple user sessions on Windows?

Comment: What is your application architecture? Database? Web service? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are an use case of the **publish / subscribe** communication model. Maybe you could add a message oriented middleware to your application and implement something similar to a "chat" system. Such a system can use a central server to forward messages (documents, commands ...) to all connected clients. For technical background information the term [**message oriented middleware**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware) is a starting point.

Advantages of existing 'message brokers' (many of them are open source) for notifications are:

- they can store messages until the receiver is online (reliable delivery), and 
  support message acknowledgement / transactions
- cross-language and cross-platform operation
- very high speed (hundreds or thousands of times faster than database queries)

Because of their generic design, they can solve many similar problems which would be harder to implement (or more resource consuming) than using databases. They can make the design of distributed systems much easier. For advanced understanding and practical guidelines, the book and the web site [Patterns and Best Practices for Enterprise Integration](http://eaipatterns.com/) by Gregor Hohpe are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

First I think your English is fine :)
I work myself with a multiuser application written in Delphi 2007 and [Bold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bold_for_Delphi). And one feature is that users can notify each other. Bold have an builtin update mechanism that is very powerful. Unfortunately it is not easy to get Bold these days as it is not for sale. You can also try to implement what you need yourself. Try search for [Delphi observer pattern](https://www.google.fi/search?hl=sv&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=HR8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=delphi%20observer%20pattern&oq=delphi%20observer%20pattern&aq=f&aqi=g-L1g-vL1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i15i19.3911l5341l0l5555l7l7l0l0l0l0l151l618l5j2l7l0.frgbld.).
To summarize this pattern is about register observers in a list. When something happens that observers should be notified about the initiator notify all observers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are on the same local network, you can use a push notification using Mailslots.  It will be instant, and lightweight.